# I can't comprehend this on SQLite3 module in Python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have been reading Python official doc on SQLite with some tutorials on other blogs.

I noticed something that I can't comprehend.

**code snippet 1**

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("chijioke.db")
cur= con.cursor()
cur.executescript("""
    create table book(
        title,
        author,
        published
    );

    insert into book(title, author, published)
    values (
        'Dirk Gently''s Holistic Detective Agency',
        'Douglas Adams',
        1987
    );
    """)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

**Code snippet 2**

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("chijioke.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.executescript("""
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book;
    CREATE TABLE book(
        title,
        author,
        published
    );

    INSERT INTO book VALUES (
        'Dirk Gently''s Holistic Detective Agency',
        'Douglas Adams',
        1987
    );
    """)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

When I ran the both code snippets, I had no error.

From what I know, SQL statements are in upper case but code snippet 1 didn't follow that rule but there was no error.

also, code snippet 1 included the names from each columns in the insert statement.

I want to know why all these changes and which code snippet is more pythonic to work with.

I will also appreciate any additional help.

Comment: This is really just a question about SQL, not about Python or its sqlite3 module.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback... I have included SQL as a tag.

Comment: SQL, at least any flavor of it I've ever used, can be in upper or lower case. I prefer upper case for keywords, but everyone does it a little different.

Comment: Also, an INSERT statement can list the columns that correspond to the `VALUES()` list that is supplied and if the list of columns is omitted, then the list of values must match the order and count of the columns (with some exceptions)

Comment: Lastly, there is no "Python" way of writing SQL since SQL is unique to the database that you are connecting to. I, personally, prefer more verbose sql, so I like the list of Columns in the INSERT statement since it leads to less ambiguity to folks that will end up reading and debugging it later on.

Comment: auto-incrementing primary keys, I have you heard of that term and can you please explain it for me.

Answer (score 0):

SQL in general is not case sensitive. You can use `insert` or `INSERT` or `InSeRt`, whatever you like. For clarity i'd recommend using uppercase. In Sqlite the table names are case sensitive, but the column names aren't. Also, like @JNevill commented, I would recommend typing out the column names in the INSERT statement to prevent future bugs, although in this script it is pretty obvious what the columns are, and there is no chance columns are added to the table somewhere along the line.

Comment: I have finally understood what everyone has been saying.